# SQL Joins when using an XREF (Codeigniter)

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join

I'm having a bit of a head scratcher .... I have a codeigniter project, on a per admin basis, I want to output a list of "departments" (General, 2nd Line, etc) and have a check box next to the relevent option if the user has been put in that department.

My vision for this is as follows;

"Admin" table

```
|admin_id|firstname|lastname|username|password
------------------------------------------------
|1.      |First   |Admin    |fadmin  |password123
|2.      |Second  |Admin    |sadmin  |password123
```

"Departments" table

```
department_id|department_name|
-----------------------------
1            |General
2            |Line
```

"Department_xref" table

```
id|admin_id|department_id
-------------------------
1 |1       |1
2 |2       |1
```

In the above example, both of my admins would have been put in the "General" department.

If I wanted to put my first admin into the 2nd Line department as well, I would have;

"Department_xref" table

```
id|admin_id|department_id
-------------------------
1 |1       |1
2 |2       |1
1 |1       |2
```

now, when I go into my admin edit view, I want to be able to see a list of all my departments (with checkboxes next to them) showing with a check which is selected currently and allowing me to select additional to add that user to more departments.

I have tried a number of queries to be able to get this but i'm hitting a wall...

I need to make sure that for any user I am editing, I can see ALL departments, and also show which department has been given access.

I would appreciate any help you can give.
thanks!

Comment: What  DataBase System did you use MySql or MsSQL?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an admin and if it won't have a massive traffic I suggest you just list all `departments` in the view and then check it against `Department_xref` sending the `department_id` and `admin_id`.

Call the model from the view in the department loop:

```
$return = $this->model->checkUserDepartment($department_id, $admin_id);
```

Check it inline on your checkbox html, if not empty then you check the checkbox:

```
if(!empty($return)): echo "checked='checked'"; endif;
```